# Error expected ';' before '{' token

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I can't find what the compiler is asking for! Did I add extra ";" or I am missing one?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

float menu;
float cm;
float in;
float indif = 0.39;
float cmdif = 2.54;
float result1 = cm * indif;
float result2 = in * cmdif; 

printf("Choose your convertion: \n\n");
printf("1. Centimeter - Inches\n");
printf("2. Inches - Centimeter\n"); 
printf("I want: ");
scanf("%f", &menu);

if ( menu < 2 ) 
{
    printf("\n\nWelcome to Centimeter > Inches converter!\n\n");
    printf("Enter your cenitmeters: ");
    scanf("%f", &cm); 
    printf("%f centimeters equals to %.2f inches!", cm, result1);
}

else ( menu > 1 )
{
    printf("\n\nWelcome to Inches > Centimeter converter!\n\n");
    printf("Enter your inches: ");
    scanf("%f", &in); 
    printf("%f inches equals to %.2f centimeters!", in, result2);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read a C book. Since when does `else` take a condition?

Comment: @Olaf You're acting like this person lacks a rudimentary knowledge of C. This is obviously a simple typo. It could happen to anyone.

Comment: @PCLuddite: Perhaps. But one would normally not ask on SO for help for a simle typo.

Comment: @Olaf They're clearly new to the site and probably don't understand what's acceptable to ask yet.

Comment: @PCLuddite: Yes, and the [tour] and [ask] are so very hard to find? Ignorantia legis non excusat.

Comment: @Olaf No, ignorance does not excuse, but you're suggestion to "read a C book" is condescending. It doesn't apply here. Nor does their lack of knowledge for the rules. It would have made more sense for you to point out the mistake and point out that's it's not acceptable, instead of assuming that the poster doesn't know C.

Comment: @PCLuddite: I recommend you find the translation. "ingnorantia" is not ignorance. That is a standard term with a deeper meaning. I think we should leave feeling maltreated to OP, or are you his alter ego?

Comment: @Olaf I studied latin for five years. I know what it means. I'm not his "alter ego". I'm defending this person who made a typo from your claim that that he's stupid. The question has been rightfully closed, so the matter is finished.

Comment: @PCLuddite: Be careful putting words into my mouth! I did not say OP is stupid! Not knowing something is not being stupid! What is your problem? EOT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
else ( menu > 1 )
```

should be

```
else if ( menu > 1 )
```

An `else` clause cannot have a condition.

Comment: Oh how stupid of me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Happens to all of us :)